# SUM Function for 2 queries

Tags: sql, fastreport

I have these below queries in fastreport. I would like sum the answer of these two queries by typing one query.. Can anyone help ?

```
SELECT 
    EAMEMID, COUNT (EAMATTNSTATUS)/2 as ABSENTDAYS1
FROM 
    viewDAILYSUM  
WHERE 
    (EAMEMID = :EAMEMID) 
    AND (EAMDATE BETWEEN :FDate AND :TDate)
    AND (EAMATTNSTATUS IN (7, 8))           
GROUP BY 
    EAMEMID  
ORDER BY 
    EAMEMID
```

---

```
SELECT 
    EAMEMID, COUNT(DISTINCT EAMDATE) ABSENTDAYS        
FROM 
    viewDAILYSUM  
WHERE 
    (EAMEMID = :EAMEMID) 
    AND (EAMDATE BETWEEN :FDate AND :TDate)
    AND (EAMATTNSTATUS IN (6))
GROUP BY 
    EAMEMID
ORDER BY 
    EAMEMID
```

Comment: Please give a short example of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was scratching my head thinking I just read this question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT EAMEMID, SUM(ABSENTDAYS) AS ABSENTDAYS FROM (
    SELECT  EAMEMID, COUNT (EAMATTNSTATUS)/2 as ABSENTDAYS
    FROM viewDAILYSUM  
    WHERE (EAMEMID = :EAMEMID) 
       AND (EAMDATE BETWEEN :FDate AND :TDate)
       AND (EAMATTNSTATUS IN (7, 8))           
    GROUP BY EAMEMID  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  EAMEMID, COUNT(DISTINCT EAMDATE) ABSENTDAYS        
    FROM viewDAILYSUM  
    WHERE (EAMEMID = :EAMEMID) 
    AND (EAMDATE BETWEEN :FDate AND :TDate)
    AND (EAMATTNSTATUS IN (6))
    GROUP BY EAMEMID
    )
GROUP BY EAMEMID
ORDER BY EAMEMID
```